# Как избавиться от большего количества переменных в python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, инспекция-кода

Имею тот такого бота с расписанием для свое группы. Хочу сделать расписание еще для одной группы, но с талкиваюсь с такой проблемой, что нужно делать огромное кол-во переменных. Как можно это упростить/исправить ? Так же вопрос, если сделать расписание для 2 групп. То бот показывал расписание именно для этой группы, тобиж чтобы бот 1 раз спросил группу и запомнил это. буду благодарен за ответ)))

```
import config
import telebot
from telebot import types

from keyboards import keyboard1, keyboard2, keyboard3

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

# Инлайн клавиатура рассписания
keyboard4 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__PN_p")  # Неделя  ПН Над чертой
keyboard4.add(item1)
keyboard5 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__PN_n")  # Неделя  ПН Под чертой
keyboard5.add(item1)

keyboard6 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__VT_p")  # Неделя ВТ Над чертой
keyboard6.add(item1)
keyboard7 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__VT_n")  # Неделя ВТ Под чертой
keyboard7.add(item1)

keyboard8 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__SR_p")  # Неделя СР Над чертой
keyboard8.add(item1)
keyboard9 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__SR_n")  # Неделя СР Под чертой
keyboard9.add(item1)

keyboard10 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__CT_p")  # Неделя ЧТ Над чертой
keyboard10.add(item1)
keyboard11 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__CT_n")  # Неделя ЧТ Под чертой
keyboard11.add(item1)

keyboard12 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__PT_p")  # Неделя ПТ Над чертой
keyboard12.add(item1)
keyboard13 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__PT_n")  # Неделя ПТ Под чертой
keyboard13.add(item1)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Альфа версия BSUT Helper. Разработчик @mikitos59', reply_markup=keyboard1)
@bot.message_handler(regexp='Расписание ')
def send_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здесь будет отображаться расписание занятий', reply_markup=keyboard3)
# Расписание занятий
@bot.message_handler(regexp='ПН')
def send_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, SV_31__PN_n, reply_markup=keyboard4, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
@bot.message_handler(regexp='ВТ')
def send_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, SV_31__VT_n, reply_markup=keyboard6, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
@bot.message_handler(regexp='СР')
def send_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, SV_31__SR_n, reply_markup=keyboard8, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
@bot.message_handler(regexp='ЧТ')
def send_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, SV_31__CT_n, reply_markup=keyboard10, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
@bot.message_handler(regexp='ПТ')
def send_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, SV_31__PT_n, reply_markup=keyboard12, parse_mode = 'Markdown')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'SV_31__PN_p':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, SV_31__PN_p, reply_markup=keyboard5, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
    elif call.data == 'SV_31__PN_n':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, SV_31__PN_n, reply_markup=keyboard4, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
    elif call.data == 'SV_31__VT_p':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, SV_31__VT_p, reply_markup=keyboard7, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
    elif call.data == 'SV_31__VT_n':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, SV_31__VT_n, reply_markup=keyboard6, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
    elif call.data == 'SV_31__SR_p':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, SV_31__SR_p, reply_markup=keyboard9, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
    elif call.data == 'SV_31__SR_n':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, SV_31__SR_n, reply_markup=keyboard8, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
    elif call.data == 'SV_31__CT_p':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, SV_31__CT_p, reply_markup=keyboard11, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
    elif call.data == 'SV_31__CT_n':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, SV_31__CT_n, reply_markup=keyboard10, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
    elif call.data == 'SV_31__PT_p':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, SV_31__PT_p, reply_markup=keyboard13, parse_mode = 'Markdown')
    elif call.data == 'SV_31__PT_n':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, SV_31__PT_n, reply_markup=keyboard12, parse_mode = 'Markdown')


# Расписание СВ-31
SV_31__PN_n = 'Понедельник (Над чертой) \n\n1⃣ - \n\n2⃣ *ФИЗИЧЕСКАЯ КУЛЬТУРА* _(9:45-11:20)_ \n\n3⃣  - \n\n4⃣ ЛЕК 103 *СТРОИТЕЛЬНАЯ МЕХАНИКА*, Леоненко Д.В. (14:00-15:30) \n\n5️⃣(1)-, \n\n    (2)ЛАБ *ХИМИЯ*, Самусева Л.В. (15:40-17:15)'
SV_31__PN_p = 'Понедельник (Под чертой) \n\n1⃣ - \n\n2⃣ *ФИЗИЧЕСКАЯ КУЛЬТУРА* _(9:45-11:20)_ \n\n3⃣  - \n\n4⃣ ЛЕК 103 *СТРОИТЕЛЬНАЯ МЕХАНИКА*, Леоненко Д.В. (14:00-15:30) \n\n5️⃣(1)ЛАБ 454 *ВОДОПОДГОТОВКА*, Горелая О.Н. (15:40-17:15), \n\n    (2)-'
SV_31__VT_n = 'Вторник (Над чертой) \n\n1⃣  ЛЕК 103 **СТРОИТЕЛЬНАЯ МЕХАНИКА**, Леоненко Д.В. _(8:00-9:30)_ \n\n2⃣  ЛЕК 317 **ВОДОПОДГОТОВКА**, Горелая О.Н. (9:45-11:20) \n\n3⃣ ПЗ 153 *СТРОИТЕЛЬНАЯ МЕХАНИКА*, Яровая А.В. (11:30-13:05) \n\n4⃣ - \n\n5️⃣ЛЕК 655 *СМЕТНОЕ ДЕЛО*, ЗАХАРЕНКО З.Н. (15:40-17:15)'
SV_31__VT_p = 'Вторник (Под чертой) \n\n1⃣  ПЗ 452 **ХИМИЯ* ВОДЫ И МИКРОБИОЛОГИЯ*, Самусева Л.В. _(8:00-9:30)_ \n\n2⃣  ЛЕК 317 **ВОДОПОДГОТОВКА**, Горелая О.Н. (9:45-11:20) \n\n3⃣ ПЗ 153 *СТРОИТЕЛЬНАЯ МЕХАНИКА*, Яровая А.В. (11:30-13:05) \n\n4⃣ - \n\n5.ПЗ 134 *СМЕТНОЕ ДЕЛО*, ЗАХАРЕНКО З.Н. (15:40-17:15)'
SV_31__SR_n = 'Среда (Над чертой) \n\n1⃣  ЛЕК 1418 *ТОСВ*, Новикова О.К. _(8:00-9:30)_ \n\n2⃣  ПЗ 153 *ТОСВ*, Новикова О.К. (9:45-11:20) \n\n3⃣ ПЗ 561 *ВОДОПОДГОТОВКА*, Горелая О.Н. (11:30-13:05) \n\n4⃣ ВОЕННАЯ ПОДГОТОВКА \n\n5️⃣ВОЕННАЯ ПОДГОТОВКА'
SV_31__SR_p = 'Среда (Под чертой) \n\n1⃣  ЛЕК 1418 *ТОСВ*, Новикова О.К. _(8:00-9:30)_ \n\n2⃣  ПЗ 134 *ТОСВ*, Новикова О.К. (9:45-11:20) \n\n3⃣ ПЗ 561 *ВОДОПОДГОТОВКА*, Горелая О.Н. (11:30-13:05) \n\n4⃣ ВОЕННАЯ ПОДГОТОВКА \n\n5️⃣ВОЕННАЯ ПОДГОТОВКА'
SV_31__CT_n = 'Четверг (Над чертой) \n\n1⃣  (1) ЛАБ 155 *ЗАЩИТА НАСЕЛЕНИЯ ОТ ЧС*, Липская М.Н., \n\n   (2) ЛАБ 154 *ВОДОПОДГОТОВКА*, Горелая О.Н. _(8:00-9:30)_ \n\n2⃣  ФИЗИЧЕСКАЯ КУЛЬТУРА (9:45-11:20) \n\n3⃣ ЛЕК 170 *ХИМИЯ*, Кудина Е.Ф. (11:30-13:05) \n\n4.ВОЕННАЯ ПОДГОТОВКА \n\n5️⃣ВОЕННАЯ ПОДГОТОВКА'
SV_31__CT_p = 'Четверг (Под чертой) \n\n1⃣  ЛЕК 266 **ВОДОПОДГОТОВКА**, Горелая О.Н. _(8:00-9:30)_\n\n2⃣ ФИЗИЧЕСКАЯ КУЛЬТУРА (9:45-11:20)\n\n3.(1)ЛАБ 452 *ХИМИЯ* ВОДЫ И МИКРОБИОЛОГИЯ, Самусева Л.В. \n    (2)ЛАБ 155 ЗАЩИТА НАСЕЛЕНИЯ ОТ ЧС, Проневич И.И. (11:30-13:05) \n\n4⃣ ВОЕННАЯ ПОДГОТОВКА \n\n5️⃣ВОЕННАЯ ПОДГОТОВКА'
SV_31__PT_n = 'Пятница (Над чертой) \n\n1⃣  (1)ЛАБ 569 *ИНФОРМАЦИОННОЕ МОДЕЛИРОВАНИЕ*, Калашник Е.Г. \n  (2)ЛАБ 552 ИНФОРМАЦИОННОЕ МОДЕЛИРОВАНИЕ, Шкурина Е.В. _(8:00-9:30)_ \n\n2⃣  ПЗ 289 ВОДОЗАБОРНЫЕ СООРУЖЕНИЯ, Вострова Р.Н. (9:45-11:20) \n\n3⃣ ПЗ 1313 БЕЛОРУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК, Курлович В.В. (11:30-13:05)'
SV_31__PT_p = 'Пятница (Под чертой) \n\n1⃣  (1)ЛАБ 569 *ИНФОРМАЦИОННОЕ МОДЕЛИРОВАНИЕ*, Калашник Е.Г. \n  (2)ЛАБ 552 ИНФОРМАЦИОННОЕ МОДЕЛИРОВАНИЕ, Шкурина Е.В. _(8:00-9:30)_ \n\n2⃣  ПЗ 289 ВОДОЗАБОРНЫЕ СООРУЖЕНИЯ, Вострова Р.Н. (9:45-11:20) \n\n3⃣ ПЗ 1313 БЕЛОРУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК, Курлович В.В. (11:30-13:05)'


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: А что значит под чертой и над чертой? Это имеется ввиду четная и нечетная неделя?

Comment: Да, это четная и не четная

Comment: Кст, нет ли опечатки в `answer` для SV_31__PN_p? Там разве не 4-я клавиатура будет? Или там используется предыдущая клавиатура?

Comment: Да вроде нету, бот полностью рабочий

Comment: Расписание запускается с реплай кнопки ПН и выводит 4 клавиатуру с инлайн кнопкой 5 клавиатуры, и так по кругу

Comment: Ага, я так и подумал :)

Comment: Насчет сохранения результата бота... Вы можете просто в файл сохранять и при запуске бота из него вычитывать. Или завести базу данных, но это по сути одно и тоже будет

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала уберите дублирование кода, например, там где создаются клавиатуры.

Если сделать функцию, что по одной кнопке вернет клавиатуру:

```
def create_one_button(**kwargs) -> types.InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(**kwargs)
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(button)
    return keyboard
    

keyboard4 = create_one_button(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__PN_p")  # Неделя  ПН Над чертой
keyboard5 = create_one_button(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__PN_n")  # Неделя  ПН Под чертой
keyboard6 = create_one_button(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__VT_p")  # Неделя ВТ Над чертой
keyboard7 = create_one_button(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__VT_n")  # Неделя ВТ Под чертой
keyboard8 = create_one_button(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__SR_p")  # Неделя СР Над чертой
keyboard9 = create_one_button(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__SR_n")  # Неделя СР Под чертой
keyboard10 = create_one_button(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__CT_p")  # Неделя ЧТ Над чертой
keyboard11 = create_one_button(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__CT_n")  # Неделя ЧТ Под чертой
keyboard12 = create_one_button(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__PT_p")  # Неделя ПТ Над чертой
keyboard13 = create_one_button(text="Следующая неделя", callback_data="SV_31__PT_n")  # Неделя ПТ Под чертой
```

Далее можно сгруппировать данные для упрощения кода в `answer`:

```
SCHEDULE_SV_31 = {
    'SV_31__PN_n': (SV_31__PN_n, keyboard4),
    'SV_31__PN_p': (SV_31__PN_p, keyboard5),
    'SV_31__VT_n': (SV_31__VT_n, keyboard6),
    'SV_31__VT_p': (SV_31__VT_p, keyboard7),
    'SV_31__SR_n': (SV_31__SR_n, keyboard8),
    'SV_31__SR_p': (SV_31__SR_p, keyboard9),
    'SV_31__CT_n': (SV_31__CT_n, keyboard10),
    'SV_31__CT_p': (SV_31__CT_p, keyboard11),
    'SV_31__PT_n': (SV_31__PT_n, keyboard12),
    'SV_31__PT_p': (SV_31__PT_p, keyboard13),
}

...

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data not in SCHEDULE_SV_31:
        return

    text, reply_markup = SCHEDULE_SV_31[call.data]
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text, reply_markup=reply_markup, parse_mode='Markdown')
```